# invoking Rest service via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to access a Java-based REST service through jQuery, the JSON from the service is as shown below.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "bookAuthor": "Bhaveh Thaker",
            "bookISBN": "ISBN 10: 0-596-52926-0",
            "bookName": "Introduction to RESTful Web Services",
            "id": "0"
        },
        {
            "bookAuthor": "Bhaveh Thaker",
            "bookISBN": "ISBN 10: 0-596-52926-0",
            "bookName": "Introduction to RESTful Web Services",
            "id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to display this data in jQuery datatable. Below is the code i am trying with jQuery Ajax.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#order-status-report', function () {
    var table = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:9090/SAPRestService/services/bookresource/getbooks",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(response.data);
            table = $('#example').DataTable({
                dom: "Tfrtip",
                data: response,
                columns: [
                    {data: "bookAuthor"},
                    {data: "bookISBN"},
                    {data: "bookName"},
                    {data: "id"}
                ]
            });
        }
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            //alert(table.cell('.selected', 0).data()+table.cell('.selected', 1).data()+table.cell('.selected', 2).data()+table.cell('.selected', 3).data());

            hello(table.cell('.selected', 0).data(), table.cell('.selected', 1).data(), table.cell('.selected', 2).data(), table.cell('.selected', 3).data());
        }
    });
});
```

I am not getting any error also, but results are not getting displayed.
What is i am missing in the above code.

Comment: You using jQuery mobile? Otherwise I can't see a reason for `pageinit` (and the event may not even be triggered).

Comment: It may be a Cross-Origin access issue. check in your navigator dev tool the Network tab then hit the XHR tag ([see image](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview)) then refresh the page and see if there is a sent request and which code is returning

Answer (score 0):

Fist off, there is no need to wait for the pageinit event, you can do the Ajax request before that:

```
var getbooks = $.getJSON("http://localhost:9090/SAPRestService/services/bookresource/getbooks");
```

now you can use the `.done()` callback of the pending request to do the event binding after the response has arrived.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#order-status-report', function () {
    getbooks.done(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: "Tfrtip",
            data: response,
            columns: [
                {data: "bookAuthor"},
                {data: "bookISBN"},
                {data: "bookName"},
                {data: "id"}
            ]
        });

        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
                $this.removeClass('selected');
            } else {
                $this.closest("tbody").find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $this.addClass('selected');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Of course this assumes that the Ajax request actually succeeds. Use the browser's developer tools to double check.

Comment: thanks for the input. I tried the same. When i print the getbooks object i am getting [object Object]. But its not getting displayed, Also its not entering into getbooks.done() method.

Comment: The getbooks object is a Deferred, you can't print it. Also, please read the last paragraph in my answer again. And of course [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926088/invoking-rest-service-via-jquery-ajax/31926312?noredirect=1#comment51764845_31926088).

Comment: Able to get the data from rest service by iterating the response. But same when i tried to give it to data table so data is getting displayed. Is there any specific format that jquery datatable expects to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem using below mentioned code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var artistURL = "http://localhost:9090/SAPRestService/services/bookresource/getbooks";
            var returnData;
             var arrayReturn = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: artistURL,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {          
                    for (prop in data) {
                    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { continue; }
                    if (data[prop] != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data[prop].length; i++) {           
                arrayReturn.push([data[prop][i]["bookAuthor"], data[prop][i]["bookISBN"],data[prop][i]["bookName"],data[prop][i]["id"]]);
                                        }
                    }
                }

                }

            });
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "sScrollY": "310px",
                "bInfo": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": true,
                "aaData": arrayReturn,
                "aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "bookAuthor" },
                { "sTitle": "bookISBN" },
                { "sTitle": "bookName" },
                { "sTitle": "id" }
                ]

            });

        });

</script>
```

Below is the corresponding html.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>bookAuthor</th>
                <th>bookISBN</th>
                <th>bookName</th>
                <th>id</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>bookAuthor</th>
                <th>bookISBN</th>
                <th>bookName</th>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

As per my observation jquery datatable expect the data in below mentioned format.

```
aaData: [
                ["A", 100],
                ["B", 25],
                ["C", 24],
                ["D", 82]
        ]
```